# Hosting WebHttp binded services in Castle WCF Facility

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

I have a WCF service, which I want to host in Castle WCF facility with multiple bindings and one of them is WebHttp. I have done same configuration as described here [Specifying Castle WCF Integration Facility Endpoint Behavior per Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749693/specifying-castle-wcf-integration-facility-endpoint-behavior-per-endpoint).
If I register IEndpointBehavior with WebHttpBehavior as anyone can guess bindings other than WebHttp fails. So I'm not registering it. In that way only TCP binding works. 
For WebHttp binding, what am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
string internalEndpointAddress = "http://localhost:8899/DummyService";

ContractDescription description = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IDummyService));

// Create webHTTP Binding            
WebHttpBinding webhttpbinding = new WebHttpBinding();

EndpointAddress webEndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(internalEndpointAddress);
    ServiceEndpoint webEndpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(description, webhttpbinding, webEndpointAddress);
    webEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

//And here is the wcf registration. To keep it clean I removed net tcp registration...

container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>(f => f.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero)
                     .Register(Component.For<IDummyService>()
                        .ImplementedBy<DummyService>()
                        .LifestyleTransient()
                        .AsWcfService(new DefaultServiceModel()
                                        .Hosted()
                                        .AddEndpoints(WcfEndpoint.FromEndpoint(webEndpoint))
                                        .PublishMetadata(o => o.EnableHttpGet())));
```

Comment: Where is it failing while hosting or calling the WCF Service?

Comment: I don't get an exception at runtime. But when I try to invoke my method with a simple http GET, it does not return a response

Comment: Are you able to browse the URL where the WCF service is hosted